# Angular 'Master' Toggle Switch

Tags: angularjs

I have several groups about 10 toggle switches. I'd like to add a single master toggle for each group that toggles all the other toggles in the group. I'd also like for the master toggle to turn off automagically if the user manually turns off any one of the toggles in the group. I am having a hard time accomplishing this without creating a feedback loop. The slave toggles have to listen to the master and all follow wherever the master goes, but the master also has to listen to each slave toggle. If all slave toggles are turned on, the master should switch on. If any slave toggles are turned off, the master switches off. Here is some almost working code:

```
angular.module('ctApp')
.service('toggleAllService', function ()
{
    function MasterToggle(masterNgModel, $element)
    {
        var _slaves = [];

        masterNgModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function ()
        {
            if ($element.is(':focus'))
            {
                _slaves.forEach(function(slaveNgModel)
                {
                    slaveNgModel.$modelValue = masterNgModel.$modelValue;
                    slaveNgModel.$render();
                });
            }
        });

        return {
            addSlave: function(slaveNgModel, $element)
            {
                _slaves.push(slaveNgModel);

                slaveNgModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function ()
                {
                    if ($element.is(':focus'))
                    {
                        var toggleMaster = _slaves.reduce(function (prevVal, slaveNgModel)
                        {
                            return !!prevVal && slaveNgModel.$modelValue;
                        }, true);

                        masterNgModel.$setViewValue(toggleMaster);
                        masterNgModel.$render();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }

    var _masters = {};

    return {
        addMaster: function (instanceName, ngModel, $element)
        {
            _masters[instanceName] = new MasterToggle(ngModel, $element);
        },
        addSlave: function (instanceName, ngModel, $element)
        {
            if (_masters[instanceName]) _masters[instanceName].addSlave(ngModel, $element);
        }
    };
})
.directive('toggleAllMaster', function (toggleAllService)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel)
        {
            toggleAllService.addMaster($attrs.toggleAllMaster, ngModel, $element);
        }
    };
})
.directive('toggleAllSlave', function (toggleAllService)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel)
        {
            toggleAllService.addSlave($attrs.toggleAllSlave, ngModel, $element);
        }
    };
});
```

This works great, except for on page load. The slave toggles don't toggle the master unless one of them has focus (i.e. the user initiated a change). I need them to change the master on page load also. How can I accomplish this mess in an elegant way?

**Edit:** Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/au3je9x3/

Comment: Would be easier if you could provide a fiddle.

Comment: Added fiddle. It works great except if the slave checkboxes are checked on page load. Add ng-init="slave1 = true; slave2 = true; slave3 = true" to the top div to see what I mean.

Comment: I basically need an angular way to differentiate between a user action to change the toggle, and a programmatic change. Seems like I could probably do this with an .on('click'), but that wouldn't be the angular way